# Access Select Minimum Numbers Maximum Date

Tags: mysql, ms-access-2010

I am working in Access 2010 and cant seem to figure out to create a query that selects the a minimum value for a field and the maximum date. I have tried the following SQL code:

```
SELECT [_ALL_NETWORKS].POINT_DESIGNATION, Min([_ALL_NETWORKS].NETWORK_NUM) AS MinNetNum, Max([_ALL_NETWORKS].ADJ_DATE) AS MaxOfADJ_DATE
FROM _ALL_NETWORKS
GROUP BY [_ALL_NETWORKS].POINT_DESIGNATION;
```

The problem with the code above is it selects the Minimum network number and the maximum adj_date from different records(i.e. selects the maximum date from a record that does not meet the criteria of minimum network number).  I want it to first find the records with the minimum network number for a point designation and then find the max date from records with the minimum network number for each point designation.

Comment: you are looking for the greatest n per group. using max and min ignore the max and min by a group but rather the only max record and the only min record.

Answer (score 0):

You should use subqueries to get you want. First filtering network_num as the minimum of your table, and then filtering the adj_date to be the maximum of the ones with minimum network_num.

```
SELECT POINT_DESIGNATION, NETWORK_NUM, ADJ_DATE 
FROM _ALL_NETWORKS
WHERE NETWORK_NUM = (SELECT MIN(NETWORK_NUM) FROM NETWORK_NUM)
  AND ADJ_DATE = (SELECT MAX(ADJ_DATE) 
                    FROM NETWORK_NUM 
                   WHERE NETWORK_NUM = (SELECT MIN(NETWORK_NUM) FROM NETWORK_NUM))
```

Comment: I cant seem to get the above solution to work.  I see there is a query within a query, but how does the `Network_Num` query get made?  Do i need to make if before i use the above solution?